# How to Cancel redirection when click on close icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML label (tag)

```
<a class="ui medium tag label m-l-1 p-r-1" href="some url">
Tag name
<i class="delete_tag delete icon"></i> <!-- to remove this tag -->
</a>
```

and this javascript code :

```
$('body').on('click','.delete_tag',function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

but when you try the **tag** I am directed to `some URL`, **I want to remove the tag without redirecting, any idea !** thanks.

Comment: Do you still want the tag itself to redirect to `some url`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

> Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event
>   will not be triggered.

```
$('body').on('click','.delete_tag',function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: The anchor will fire if you click on it. The anchor will no longer fire if you click the delete tag icon.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your after

```js
$("#delete-on-click").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("a i.delete_tag").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id ="delete-on-click" class="ui medium tag label m-l-1 p-r-1" href="some url">
Tag name
<i class="delete_tag delete icon">awdawdawdawd</i> <!-- to remove this tag -->
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below snippet. Hope this will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete_tag').on('click',function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
        return false;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a class="ui medium tag label m-l-1 p-r-1" href="some url">
<i class="delete_tag delete icon">Tag name</i>
```